# Method intercepted twice even though it was called once

Tags: java, bytecode, agent, byte-buddy

In the following code snippet I'm calling the method `doStuff` once on an instance of `Subclass`. However it is intercepted twice.

Note that `doStuff` was defined in the parent class `SuperClass`. If `doStuff` was defined in `SubClass` the interception logic would work as expected: only one interception.

Am I using Byte Buddy incorrectly?

```
package com.test;

import static net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.any;
import static net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.nameStartsWith;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent;
import net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder;
import net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription;
import net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType.Builder;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodDelegation;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.RuntimeType;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.SuperCall;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ReproBugTest {

    @Test
    public void reproBug() {

        new AgentBuilder.Default().type(nameStartsWith("com.test"))
                                    .transform(new AgentBuilder.Transformer() {

                                        @Override
                                        public Builder<?> transform(
                                                Builder<?> builder,
                                                TypeDescription td) {

                                            return builder.method(any())
                                                            .intercept(
                                                                    MethodDelegation.to(MethodInterceptor.class));
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .installOn(
                                            ByteBuddyAgent.installOnOpenJDK());

        SubClass subClass = new SubClass();
        subClass.doStuff();
    }
}

class SuperClass {
    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("Doing stuff...");
    }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {
}

class MethodInterceptor {

    @RuntimeType
    public static Object intercept(@SuperCall Callable<?> zuper)
            throws Exception {

        // Intercepted twice, bug?
        System.out.println("Intercepted");

        Object returnValue = zuper.call();

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are intercepting the method call for every type, i.e. for both `Subclass` and `SuperClass`. You need to further specify your interceptor for what methods to intercept. In you case, you only want to intercept methods if they are declared by a given type.

This is easy to implement. Instead of `builder.method(any())`, you should intercept `builder.method(isDeclaredBy(td))`. This way, a method is only intercepted if it is declared by the intercepted type.

Finally, I can see from, your source code that you are using an older version of Byte Buddy. Version *0.7-rc6* runs stable, has additional features  and fixes several bugs. (However, some APIs still need to be changed.)

Comment: This snippet runs on 0.7-rc6 but I may still be using some old APIs. Oh and btw the online javadoc for 0.7-rc6 seems broken: http://bytebuddy.net/javadoc/0.7-rc6/index.html

Comment: The Byte Buddy agent method `ByteBuddyAgent.installOnOpenJDK()` should be `ByteBuddyAgent.install()` as it supports J9 and any Java 9-compatible platforms. Thanks for the hint to the javadoc, was a naming issue. It's fixed now.